# regex on htaccess not working as expected

Tags: htaccess, regex

I have this rule on my .htaccess that doesn't work as I would expect:

```
RewriteRule ^/rg$ /download/file_1.pdf [NC,L]
```

I would like to redirect all the requests from `www.example.com/rg` to download this file: `www.example.com/download/file_1.pdf` but so far nothing happens...

Am I missing something?

Comment: thanks MrWhite, I'm really a newbie... ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `.htaccess` the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. So, the regex should be `^rg$`, not `^/rg$`. In other words:

```
RewriteRule ^rg$ /download/file_1.pdf [NC,L]
```

Specifically, the directory-prefix that leads to the `.htaccess` file is first removed from the requested URL-path before the match occurs. This directory-prefix always ends with a slash, so the URL-path never starts with a slash.

This contrasts to when the directive is used in a server (or virtualhost) context, when you do need the slash prefix, since it matches the full URL-path (there is no directory-prefix in a server context).

Comment: thanks a lot, but what if I require to have a slash before the string "rg"? For example to avoid matching other string that ends with "rg"?

Comment: sorry, now I get it... "This directory-prefix always ends with a slash, so the URL-path never starts with a slash." Thanks again

Comment: Yes, the regex `^rg$` actually matches the requested URL `/rg` (exactly). This is unique to mod_rewrite (in a directory/`.htaccess` context). By contrast, the mod_alias directives `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` would require you to match against the slash prefix (ie. the full URL-path).